# Laravel return flash message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, flash-message

I am trying to return a flash message depending on the outcome of an function however I don't really know how to do this properly, can someone help me with fixing this?

Controller:

```
 public function postDB(Requests\NameRequest $request) {
    $newName = trim($request->input('newName'));
    $newLat = $request->input('newCode');
    $websites = new Website();
    $websites->name = $newName;
    $websites->html = $newLat;
    $websites->save();
    if ($websites->save())
    {
    $message = 'success';
    }else{
    $message = 'error';
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('message', 'Profile updated!');
}
```

Request:

```
   public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {   
    return [
       'img' => 'file|image',
    ];   
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'img.image' => 'File type is not supported! Use files with extension .jpg/.jpeg/.gif',
        ];
    }
```

Template:

```
@if (session('status'))
@if (session('status')=="success")
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('message') }}
    </div>
@else
    <div class="alert alert-error">
       {{ session('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
@endif
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('home', 'BuilderController@homepage');
    Route::get('pages', 'BuilderController@websites');
    Route::get('template', 'BuilderController@templates');
    Route::post('template2', 'BuilderController@postDB');
    Route::post('template', 'BuilderController@testing');
    Route::get('logout', 'BuilderController@getLogout');
    Route::get('/website/{name}', 'BuilderController@website');
});
```

Comment: What's the problem u r facing ?

Comment: problem is I am not getting any message either if it's success or not

Comment: Why do you have the same if statement twice in testing()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution :**

There could be only one reason for this issue.

The laravel will pass the flash messages only if it's registered inside the middleware web

i.e.,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
   //The back()'s url should be registered here
});
```

**Update :**

It seems you need to redirect back with message and inputs

So, You can do like this

```
if ($request->hasFile('img')) {
    $message = 'success';
    } else {
    $message = 'error';
}
return redirect()->back()->withInput()->->with('message', $message);
```

**Update 2 :**

```
@if (session('status'))
@if (session('status')=="success")
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        Congrats! Everything was fine
    </div>
@else
    <div class="alert alert-error">
       Oops! Something went wrong
    </div>
@endif
@endif
```

**Note :**  You can pass the status param to your wish

Comment: Check my question again I have uploaded Routes, it doesn't work still, is it because of 2 return?

Comment: You can check for `status` inside your view

Comment: how? I have this: !@if (session('status'))
 <div id="mydiv" class="alert alert-success">
  {{ session('status') }}
 </div>
 !@endif

Comment: Have updated how to retrieve it in view. It's our wish to pass the param and retrieve it

Comment: I did just as your example has showed but I still have no message

Comment: Sorry, just change this `return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('message', $message);
`

Comment: believe it or not, still no message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137490/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-przemek).

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `message` as a flash parameter name, use it, not `status`.

```
@if (session('message'))
@if (session('message')=="success")
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        Congrats! Everything was fine
    </div>
@else
    <div class="alert alert-error">
       Oops! Something went wrong
    </div>
@endif
@endif
```